# Laravel 7 dynamic "add fields" form. foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given

Tags: javascript, php, foreach, laravel-7, dynamicform

This my first post here, but by no mean my first time visiting. I'm an amateur coder and I'm working on something that has stumped me for passed day or two...

I'm building a site using Laravel 7. One of the pages includes a dynamic form that allows the user to add addition for fields as needed.

I'm am generating the dynamic form fields and a tinymce editor as well as submitting the form using javascript.

The issue I'm running into is this:

Upon clicking the 'Submit' button the page does not transition or show any signs of having been submitted. The first portion of the form data is successfully submitted and added to the appropriate database table but the dynamic fields are not added to their table and an error is thrown in the browser console.

The believe the relevant issue is `message "foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given"` as this seems to be where the code stops running and things go wrong.

This function applies to the dynamic `image_id[]` portion of the form.

The full error info is:

```
XHR POST https://www.mydomainname.com/create
[HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 479ms]
```

**Request:**

```
format  "galleries"
title   "This+is+the+title+of+the+content"
short   "This+is+the+short+description+for+the+content."
thumb   "https://www.mydomainname.com/storage/giraffe1.jpg"
category    "funny"
image_id    […]
0   "Image+1"
1   "Image+2"
2   "Image+3"
```

**Response:**

```
message "foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given"
exception   "ErrorException"
file    "/home/user/site/app/Http/Controllers/ContentController.php"
line    149
trace   [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
```

**Line 149**:

```
foreach($request->input('image_id[]') as $key => $image) {
```

This is my **Blade View**, including the **Javascript**:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Post New Content')
@section('content')

    <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/arx09ivbx1ikchqgcvc6558h9sx2crokpd2c1152g667mh0c/tinymce/6/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendor/laravel-filemanager/js/stand-alone-button.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">

                @if (session('status'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        {{ session('status') }}
                    </div>
                @endif
                    <div class="alert alert-danger print-error-msg" style="display:none">
                        <ul></ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="alert alert-success print-success-msg" style="display:none">
                        <ul></ul>
                    </div>

                <div class="card shadow">
                    <h2 class="card-header">
                        Post a New Gallery
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" style="float: right" href="{{ url()->previous() }}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure? All progress will be lost!')">Go Back</a>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
                            <input type="hidden" name="format" value="galleries" class="form-control" required>
                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <strong>Title:</strong>
                                    <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <strong>Description:</strong>
                                    <input type="text" name="short" class="form-control" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <strong>Thumbnail:</strong>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                                <input type="text" id="thumb" class="form-control" name="thumb" aria-label="thumb" aria-describedby="button-image" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="button-image">Browse</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <strong>Category: </strong>
                                        <select name="category" class="form-control" required>
                                            <option value="" disabled selected>Select content category...</option>
                                            @foreach($allCategories as $category)
                                                <option value="{{ $category->name }}">{{ ucfirst(trans($category->name)) }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <br>

            <!-- Dynamic Fields -->                
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="image_id[]" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                        <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
            </div>
            <!-- End Dynamic Fields -->

        </form>
    </div>
</div>


                </div>
            </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var postURL = "<?php echo url('create'); ?>";
        var i=1;

        $('#add').click(function(){
            i++;
            $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added">' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="image_id[]" class="form-control name_list" /></td>' +
                '<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td>' +
                '</tr>');
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
        });

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $('#submit').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:postURL,
                method:"POST",
                data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
                type:'json',
                success:function(data)
                {
                    if(data.error){
                        printErrorMsg(data.error);
                    }else{
                        i=1;
                        $('.dynamic-added').remove();
                        $('#add_name')[0].reset();
                        $(".print-success-msg").find("ul").html('');
                        $(".print-success-msg").css('display','block');
                        $(".print-error-msg").css('display','none');
                        $(".print-success-msg").find("ul").append('<li>Record Inserted Successfully.</li>');
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        function printErrorMsg (msg) {
            $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").html('');
            $(".print-error-msg").css('display','block');
            $(".print-success-msg").css('display','none');
            $.each( msg, function( key, value ) {
                $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").append('<li>'+value+'</li>');
            });
        }
    });

</script>

            <script>
                document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                    document.getElementById('button-image').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        window.open('/file-manager/fm-button', 'fm', 'width=1400,height=800');
                    });
                });

                // set file link
                function fmSetLink($url) {
                    document.getElementById('thumb').value = $url;
                }
            </script>

    @endsection
```

And here is my **Controller**:

```
public function createPost(Request $request)
    {


        $post = new Content();
        $post->title = $request->get('title');
        $post->short = $request->get('short');
        $post->long = $request->get('long');
        $post->thumb = $request->get('thumb');
        $post->format = $request->get('format');
        $post->category = $request->get('category');
        $post->author = Auth::user()->id;
        $post->save();

        $order = 0;

        foreach($request->input('image_id[]') as $key => $content) {

                $contentImg = new ContentImages();
                $contentImg->content_id = $post->id;
                $contentImg->image_id = $content->image_id;
                $contentImg->image_order = $order+1;
                $contentImg->save();
            }

            return response()->json(['success'=>'done']);
    }
```

And, finally, my **Routes**:

```
Route::get("create","ContentController@create");
Route::post("create","ContentController@createPost");
```

**Things I Have Tried**

I've tried several variations of the image_id syntax and nothing seems to be working...

As posted above:

```
foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given
```

Using `$request->input('image_id')`:

```
"Attempt to read property \"image_id\" on string"
```

I tried `$request('image_id')` and got:

```
Object of type Illuminate\Http\Request is not callable
```

Then I tried `$request->input(['image_id'])` which just gave

```
foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given
```

The output from `dd($request->input('image_id')` is:

```
array:2 [
  0 => "Name 1"
  1 => "Name 2"
]
```

and `dd($request->input('image_id[]'))` gave `null`.

**Output of `dd($request->all())`**:

```
array:6 [
  "format" => "galleries"
  "title" => "Thoughtless Driver Ruins Everyone's Day at the Wildlife Park"
  "short" => "This lady made a mess at the West Midland Safari Park. The Giraffe was not injured."
  "thumb" => "https://www.mydomainname.com/storage/photos/1/6317a2b460c98.jpg"
  "category" => "oops"
  "image_id" => array:3 [
    0 => "Name 1"
    1 => "Name 2"
    2 => "Name 3"
  ]
]
```

I'm really lost on this one.

Any guidance here would be GREATLY appreciated, as well as any recommendations on better ways to handle this scenario.

I'm a marginally talented amateur with this stuff but nowhere near expert and I'm always looking to learn.

Much thanks in advance!!

SMR

Comment: I don't have a system available to check, but I believe the foreach simply needs: `$request->input('image_id')`? ... if that doesn't work, then just before the foreach add a `dd($request->input('image_id[]');` or `dd($request->input('image_id');`, or maybe even `dd($request);` to see how the `input_id` appears in the request.

Comment: Okay, @PaulT. so I tried that and get `"Attempt to read property \"image_id\" on string"` and the same behavior as previous. As for the request, it is coming through as an array... `image_id[], 0 = image+1, 1 = image+2, etc....`. If you look above in the "Response" section of the error I posted you can see what is coming through.

Comment: What is your output of $request->all(); maybe do a print_r or var_dump on $request->all();

Comment: @Yeak -  `dd($request->all())` results in the above new snippet at the bottom of the main post. Using var_dump or print_r both just resulted in the image_id fields being skipped all together and the other data being posted to the first table. It did however cause the "Record added successfully" message to appear where without it, it did not. But yeah, the output is basically the same as the **Response** portion of the error at the top of the post... still no progress made.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I figured out what I was doing wrong.

`$request->input('image_id')` was the correct solution.

My issue was further down. Once I corrected to `$request->input('image_id')`, this lead to another error, `"Attempt to read property \"image_id\" on string"`, but this was actually due to a syntax error further down the page.

Fixed that, and all is now well!

Thank you to those who helped!